# Como imprimir lo seleccionado en mi buscador a un pdf

Tags: php, html, fpdf

Tengo este **buscador** que lo que hace es mostrarme todos los datos de los valores estáticos, dinámicos, que estan relacionados a mi tabla **cliente** de mi base de datos llamada **mitienda** con los parámetros **[ name, email ]** de mi tabla **cliente**

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';
////////////////// VARIABLES DE CONSULTA////////////////////////////////////
$where="";
$name=$_POST['xnombre'];
$email=$_POST['xcarrera'];
////////////////////// BOTON BUSCAR //////////////////////////////////////
if (isset($_POST['buscar']))
{
    if (empty($_POST['xcarrera']))
    {
        $where="where name like '".$name."%'";
    }

    else if (empty($_POST['xnombre']))
    {
        $where="where email='".$email."'";
    }

    else
    {
        $where="where name like '".$name."%' and email='".$client."'";
    }
}
/////////////////////// CONSULTA A LA BASE DE DATOS ////////////////////////
$cliente="SELECT * FROM cliente $where $limit";
$resClientes=$conexion->query($cliente);
$resCarreras=$conexion->query($clientes);

<html lang="es">
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="alert alert-info">
            <h2>Filtro de Búsqueda PHP</h2>
            </div>
        </header>
        <section>
            <form method="post">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre..." name="xnombre"/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email..." name="xcarreras"/>
                <button name="buscar" type="submit">Buscar</button>
            </form>
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>

                <?php

                while ($registroAlumnos = $resClientes->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))
                {

                    echo'<tr>
                         <td>'.$registroAlumnos['id'].'</td>
                         <td>'.$registroAlumnos['name'].'</td>
                         <td>'.$registroAlumnos['email'].'</td>
                         </tr>';
```

Pero estoy deseando que mi **fpdf** imprima solo lo que yo seleccione en mi buscador, pero el **fpdf** imprime toda la tabla en si, no lo que yo seleccione en mi buscador, como puedo hacer posible que el fpdf filtre y muestre solo lo que yo seleccione en el buscador

```
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
require 'conexion.php';
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM cliente";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta);
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',16);

while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    $pdf->Cell(30, 10, $row['id'], 1, 0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(70, 10, $row['name'], 1, 0, 'C', 0);
    $pdf->Cell(35, 10, $row['email'], 1, 0, 'C', 0);
}
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: Observa la consulta que estás ejecutando en el bloque donde generas el PDF: `$consulta = "SELECT * FROM cliente";` Si quieres que te filtre por algo, debes indicarlo en la consulta, poniendo algo como `$consulta = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE ...."`  Dado que estás trabajando con una Clase, lo suyo sería sacar la consulta SQL del contexto de la clase, creando un método que reciba los datos que necesitas y a partir de ahí cree el PDF, así, podrás usar tu clase PDF para generar PDFs de cualquier contenido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que en tu clase `PDF` estás ejecutando esta consulta:

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM cliente";
```

Y luego creando el conjunto de resultados de la misma para crear el PDF. Esa consulta no tiene ningún filtro, trae todos los clientes. Si los quieres filtrados tienes que indicar el filtro que quieres, en tu consulta, algo como:

```
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE -- Aquí los criterios de filtro";
```

Por otra parte, tu clase `PDF` es poco útil como la tienes ahora. Las clases se crean generalmente para ser reutilizadas. Pero si metes dentro de la clase, tanto la conexión a la BD, como una consulta en específico, esa clase no te servirá para imprimir otros PDFs, los cuales pueden venir o no de la base de datos y pueden estar basados en otras tablas, no solo clientes, o en archivos de texto, o en JSON, o en contenido HTML.

Te mostraré brevemente una forma simple de hacer tu clase un poco más útil. Lo que he hecho ha sido crear un método llamado  `getClients()` para obtener la lista de clientes. Si necesitas luego una lista de empleados, puedes agregarle otro método a la clase que genere esa lista y puedes hacer cosas más complejas, como generar cualquier PDF desde un solo método, pasándole parámetros y demás, pero no nos metamos en eso ahora... Lo dejo caer simplemente para tener presente que una de las grandes ventajas de la POO es poder **reutilizar código**.

Este sería la clase:

```
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
class PDF extends FPDF
{
    /*Quitamos la conexión de aquí, lo mejor es pasarle los datos desde fuera*/
    /* new PDF() no es necesario*/
    /*Y usamos $this en todo esto,porque la clase extiende de FPDF*/
    $this->AliasNbPages();
    $this->AddPage();
    /*
       Este y otros parámetros pueden hacerse dinámicos, 
       así puedes usar la misma clase para generar cualquier PDF
       con cualquier fuente y tamaño
    */
    $this->SetFont('Arial','',16);

    public function getClients($mData) {
        foreach($mData as $row){
            /*NÓTESE que usamos $this aquí también*/
            $this->Cell(30, 10, $row['id'], 1, 0, 'C', 0);
            $this->Cell(70, 10, $row['name'], 1, 0, 'C', 0);
            $this->Cell(35, 10, $row['email'], 1, 0, 'C', 0);
        }
        /* Retornamos el PDF*/
        return $this->Output();
    }
}
?>
```

---

Ahora, **desde cualquier contexto**, como por ejemplo el primer bloque de código de tu pregunta:

1. Conectarías a la Base de datos
2. Lanzarías la consulta
3. Harías include de tu clase `PDF`  y llamarías al método que te genera la lista de clientes.

Un ejemplo de uso contextual sería justo lo que tenías en el cuerpo de la clase `PDF` y que la amarraba a ese único contexto, haciéndola **inútil para otros contextos y por tanto rompiendo uno de los propósitos de la POO que es reutilizar código**.

**Estamos en otro archivo, en cualquier contexto**, digamos que este es el contexto 341 en una apliación enorme ...

```
require 'conexion.php';
requiere 'elNombreDeArchivoDeTuClasePDF.php';

/*Para prueba, pedimos sólo 5 clientes*/
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM cliente LIMIT 5";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta);
/*Este array guardará las filas del resultado*/
$mData=array();
while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    /*Vamos llenando $mData con cada fila*/
    $mData[]=$row;
}

/*Una vez lleno el array creamos la instancia de PDF*/
$pdf = new PDF();

/*Llamamos nuestro método*/
$mPDF=$pdf->getClientes($mData);
/*Usar $mPDF para lo que necesites*/
```

Es importante que comprendas la diferencia entre un uso contextual (en una aplicación puede haber miles o millones de contextos) y lo que es una clase. En los métodos de la clase puede haber operaciones simples (como el ejemplo de `getClientes()` o muy complejas) y el propósito de la clase es encapsular esos procesos, de modo que luego no tengas que andar rompiéndote el coco en esos múltiples contextos, definiendo ***cómo tiene que hacerse esto o aquello***, porque eso ya lo defines en la clase.

Supongamos que necesitas ahora una lista de empleados, entonces dotarías a la clase `PDF` de un método `getEmpleados()` donde defines la forma en que debe obtenerse esa lista. Y, si estás en una aplicación donde deberían crearse PDFs de miles o millones de cosas distintas, entonces te ls podrías ingeniar para crear un método que reciba ciertos parámetros y sea capaz de generarte cualquier tipo de lista o documento PDF con ese sólo método, así, la clase PDF no tiene mil métodos, sino uno, dos o tres, que producen salidas de un mismo género.

Bueno, me he alargado un poco, pero creo que es importante hacer la diferencia entre un uso contextual y la clase en POO, sino rápidamente tienes un spaghetti de código y te encuentras con que realmente no estás progamando en POO, aunque uses clases y demás.